# Prove that if A is symmetric, then $ \ker(A) = \ker(A^n)$ for all $ n ∈ N.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is my proof.

If A is a symmetric matrix, then $A^T = A,$ by definition.

Therefore, since this is the case, 
$\ker(A^T) = \ker(A)$,

proof by induction:
if we let n = 1.

Then $\ker(A^T) = \ker(A^1)$
$\ker(A^T+1) = \ker(A^2)$

Is this is sufficient proof?

Comment: No, it's not. If you want to proceed by induction, you have successfully shown the claim for the "base case" $n=1$, and now you have to establish that if the claim holds for some arbitrary natural $n > 1$ then the identity can be deduced for $n+1$. The claim will then follow by the principle of induction.

Comment: You should use the fact that $A$ is diagonalisable.

Answer (score 3):

Induction: $\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)$ follows from $\|Ax\|^2 = \langle Ax,Ax\rangle = \langle A^2x,x\rangle$. Assume now that $\ker(A^n) = \ker(A)$ for some $n$. Then
$$
A^{n+1}x = 0\;\Longleftrightarrow\;A^2A^{n-1}x = 0\;\Longleftrightarrow\;AA^{n-1}x = 0\;\Longleftrightarrow\;A^nx = 0,
$$
and thus $\ker(A^{n+1}) = \ker(A^n) = \ker(A)$.

Remark: Note that in the induction step, we have not used the symmetry of $A$. This is a general principle. Whenever for a linear map $F$ we have that $\ker(F^{n+1}) = \ker(F^n)$, then $\ker(F^m) = \ker(F^n)$ for all $m\ge n$. The lowest $n$ with this property is called the *ascend* of $F$. For a symmetric matrix the ascend is one.

Comment: Why do people insist on diagonalization? I thought your approach is the obvious way.

Comment: Because some people think in matrices, others in terms of linear maps.

Comment: The base case is a bit unclear/unmotivated, at least to me (that ker$(A^TA) = $ker$(A)$)

Comment: @Nitin: $A$ is a symmetric matrix, i.e. $A=A^T$

Comment: Yes I realize this, but showing that the kernel of $A^TA$ in the kernel of $A$ is bit of a nontrivial step and worth showing in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should prove this way. Since $A$ is symmetric, it is similar to diagonal matrix, i.e. there is invertible $P$ such that 
$$
P^{-1}AP=\pmatrix{\lambda_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && \lambda_n}
$$
Hence
$$
P^{-1}A^nP=\pmatrix{\lambda_1^n \\ & \ddots \\ && \lambda_n^n}
$$
The rank of $A$ is the number of nonzero eigenvalues. So $r(A)=r(A^n)$ and
$$
\dim\ker(A) = n-r(A)=n-r(A^n)=\dim\ker(A^n)
$$
Since $\ker(A)\subset \ker(A^n)$, we have $\ker(A)=\ker(A^n)$.

Comment: You're missing two $\dim$ there. You've shown that the kernel of $A$ and $A^n$ have the same dimension. We need to use $\ker A \subset \ker A^n$ as well to show equality of the null _spaces_.