# Prove that if $A$ is symmetric, then $im(A) = im(A^n)$ for all $ n ∈ N.$

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I prove this?
Can I do a proof by induction like this?

for n = 1, the following is true.
im(A) = im(A^1)
im(A^1) = im(A^2).

Since the image never changes for a linear function, this is always true.

Is that a sufficient proof? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Usually Ran or Img is used for the image.  $\text{im}$ could be interpreted as "imaginary part".

Answer (score 1):

I assume that we are talking about real matrices. In that case, a symmetric matrix $A$ is diagonalizable. The image $A$ is the span of all eigenvectors corresponding to non-zero eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1706407/prove-that-if-a-is-symmetric-then-kera-keran-for-all-n-%E2%88%88-n/1706611?noredirect=1#comment3483386_1706611) for proofs for the statement that $\ker(A^n) = \ker(A)$. Now, since $A^n$ is symmetric, $im(A^n) = \ker(A^n)^\perp = \ker(A)^\perp = im(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is true for **real** symmetric matrices.  In the case of complex symmetric (but not hermitian) matrices, the statement is false.  For example, consider
$$ A = \pmatrix{-1 & i\cr i & 1\cr},\ A^2 = \pmatrix{0 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr}$$